# Если "испытать" - "испытуемый", то есть ли "сказуемый", "наказуемый"?

Tags: словообразование

Скажите, пожалуйста, какая словообразовательная связь между словами "испытать/испытывать" и "испытуемый"?

Раньше было правило, непосредственно связывающее эти два слова по грамматике?

Или, может быть, было слово "**испытовать", от которого могло бы образоваться слово "испытуемый"?

А как между "связывать" и "связующий"? Еще есть такие слова, как "сказуемое", "наказуемый".

Comment: @Quassnoi what your edit is meant for? Why are u reverting to incorrect spelling?

Comment: @Anixx: because the OP surmises there was a word *испытовать* (sic) which would produce *испытуемый*. Such a word did really exist, so the op's guess is right.

Answer (score 4):

"Испытуемый" - [страдательное причастие настоящего времени](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CF%F0%E8%F7%E0%F1%F2%E8%E5_(%EB%E8%ED%E3%E2%E8%F1%F2%E8%EA%E0)#.D0.A1.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.8F.D1.89.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D0.B2.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8). Они образованы от глаголов несовершенного вида, переходных с помощью суффиксов -ем- и -им-. *Тот, на кого направлено действие глагола*, or **passive** side of action.

"Связующий" - [действительное причастие настоящего времени](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CF%F0%E8%F7%E0%F1%F2%E8%E5_(%EB%E8%ED%E3%E2%E8%F1%F2%E8%EA%E0)#.D0.94.D0.B5.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.8F.D1.89.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D0.B2.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8). Образованы от глаголов несовершенного вида, переходных и непереходных с помощью суффиксов -ущ- (-ющ-), и -ащ- (-ящ-). *Тот, кто направлено действие глагола*, or **active** side of action.

Почитайте вообще про причастия и отглагольные прилагательные, думаю многие вопросы отпадут.

Comment: "Тот, кто направлено действие глагола" - здесь опечатка

Answer (score 3):

Those words are Church Slavonic borrowings, derived from CS *сказовати*, *испытовати*, *связовати*.

From Vostokov's *Русская Грамматика*:

> Некоторые глаголы сего отделения на *-ывать* принимают в первой отрасли двоякое окончание: *-ываю* и *-yю* или *-у́ю*. Таковы суть: *испове́дываю* и *испове́дую*, *пропове́дываю* и *пропове́дую*, *испы́тываю* и *испыту́ю*, *ука́зываю* и *указу́ю*, *ска́зываю* и *сказу́ю*, *свя́зываю* и *связу́ю*, *обя́зываю* и *обязу́ю*. Последнее окончание принадлежит важной речи и имеет в церковном Словенском языке соответствующее ceбе окончание второй отрасли *-овал*, *-oвaть*, вместо *-ывал*, *-ывать*; напр. *пропове́довати*, *испы́товати*, *ска́зовати*, *свя́зовати* и пр.

There is also an opposite example: CS had *завѣдовати*, while Russian had *заведывать*. Until quite recently, the CS form and the proper Russian form were used in parallel, and the Russian form and its derivatives (*заведывающий*, *заведываю* etc.) had been prevalent for some time (early XX century).

However, nowadays the CS form (*заведовать*) is used, and the Russian form is perceived as archaic.

Comment: This is quite the whole answer. Испытывать, сказывать, связывать and наказывать had versions with -овать in OCS, from which the participles with -уемый are derived. It is not a regular model for the modern normative language, though.

Answer (score 0):

Я могу только сказать, что "испытать/испытывать" (глагол) и "испытуемый" (прилагательное) — однокоренные слова. В настоящее время слова "испыт**о**вать" нет, оно выглядит похожим на слово "испыт**ы**вать" с опечаткой. Испытуемый — это *тот, кто подвергается испытанию*, или *кого испытывают*.
Пожалуйста, объясните подробнее, что имеется в виду под "правилом, несредственно связывающее эти два слова по грамматике"?

"Сказуемое", "наказуемый" лишь звучат похоже на "связывать/связующий".
"Сказуемое" — прилагательное, имеет корень "сказ", как в слове "сказать".
"Наказуемый" — прилагательное, однокоренное с "наказать" и "дать *наказ/приказ*" (дать задание).

Comment: Есть у меня подозрение, что «сказуемое» и «наказуемый» - это имена существительные. Вам так не кажется?

Comment: Вы правы, сказуемое — существительное ([http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/сказуемое](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/сказуемое)), наказуемый — прилагательное ([http://slovari.yandex.ru/наказуемый](http://slovari.yandex.ru/наказуемый))

Comment: То есть, вопрос «кто?» к слову «наказуемый» задать нельзя?

Comment: @YellowSky В принципе, можно, но почти никогда это слово так не используется. Живое существо обычно не может быть наказуемым, а о наказуемых поступках... ну, можно сказать «наказуемое» («Я совершил наказуемое»), но это специально выдумывать надо. Обычно слово употребляется как полное или краткое прилагательное. Вот в 18-19 веке "наказуемый" применялось и по отношению к людям.

Comment: @Shady_arc - Не подумайте, пожалуйста, что я придираюсь, просто я сторонник строгой терминологии.
_Заметив средь публики своего малолетнего сына, наказуемый велел ему идти домой и сказать матери, что папа еще немного покатается по городу, а затем явится домой к обеду._ [Максим Соколов. 10.XI -- 16.XI (2001) // «Известия», 2001.11.16](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%E0%EA%E0%E7%F3%E5%EC%FB%E9&docid=22352) Есть ещё много примеров, но кол-во знаков тут огра

Comment: В строгой терминологии "наказуемый" является прежде всего прилагательным, изредко переходящим в существительное. У слова "слепой" гораздо больше прав считаться существительным. "Наказуемый" же, очевидно, почти никто не использует как в вашем примере (я про современный язык).

Comment: @Shady_arc - Извините, но слово «глоттохронология» тоже почти никто не использует, однако от этого оно никуда не девается и свойст своих не меняет. Просто расценивайте всё, что я написал выше, как призыв к тому, чтобы смотреть на вещи с разных сторон. Не более того.

Comment: For Russian it is common to nominalize adjectives and participles and to adjectivize participles - and most incommon to adjectivize nouns. So it is wiser to say that наказуемый is participle or adjective (which can be nominalized, though) than to name it noun. As well as слепой.

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически от "связывать"  страдательный залог (аналогичный) будет "связываемый". Может быть и можно сказать "связуемый" (чисто грамматически) но спел-чекер подчеркивает :D

Для наказывать будет "наказываемый", как я понимаю, хотя, классика жанра "Не наказуемо!"(с), но это из другой оперы.

Comment: Действие не наказуемо, а сделавший действие как раз и будет наказуемый или наказываемый.

Comment: @Artemix: *уголовно наказуемое деяние* is quite a common expression.

Comment: @Quassnoi Ну да, я и имел в виду что действие "не наказуемо" а человек будет "наказуемый" или "наказываемый". Т.е. "классика жанра" "Не наказуемо!" относится к действию, а не к человеку.